# I am trying to change the working directory within a loop based on the level of a factor variable in R

Tags: r

I work in a school district and plan to produce unique PDF reports that I will send to a shared drive containing a folder for each of the 40+ schools in my district.

I am trying to set the working directory within my `for` loop so that each school will get a report tailored for their school.  The schools files are named based on the levels of some variable named "school_name" and now I want to write to those folders based upon the fact that I am using data for school[i].

```
schools <- levels(as.factor(data$school_name))
for (i in 1:length(schools)) {
  setwd("W:\\Data Analysis Results\\"paste(schools[[i]]))
  ## some command to create a unique PDF report for school [[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This minor change should do it:

```
schools <- levels(as.factor(data$school_name))
for (i in 1:length(schools)) {
  setwd(file.path("W:/Data Analysis Results", schools[[i]]))
  # some command to create a unique PDF report for school [[i]]
}
```

The file.path function is made for these tasks.

Comment: Forgot about `file.path`; that is a better approach.

Comment: file.path worked but I had to change the backslashes in the address:                                                                setwd(file.path("W:\\Data Analysis\\", schools[[i]]))

Comment: @user1383049 - That's strange. `file.path("W:/Data Analysis Results", "foo.txt")` work fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

You have the `paste` in the wrong place:

```
setwd(paste0("W:\\Data Analysis Results\\",schools[[i]]))
```

or if you have an older version of R without `paste0`

```
setwd(paste("W:\\Data Analysis Results\\",schools[[i]],sep=""))
```